# A object property value is showing while the other refrence object is null

Tags: javascript, object

```
var obj={name: "faizan"}
    var obj2= obj;//obj2 pointing to the same memoray location of obj
    console.log("before making null obj",obj2.name);
    obj={};  //obj became null
      console.log("after making null obj",obj2.name);//now this will need to be null but is working why??
```

i made object (obj) then assigned it to the second object (obj2) and finally make obj null
but after that obj2.name showing me "faizan". why? it need to show nothing cause obj null now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you believe it to work is incorrect. The second time you set `obj = {};` you aren't nullifying the original object. You are instead creating an entirely new empty object, while obj2 still references the original.

You could achieve what you think by using a parent container:

```
var obj = { container: { name: 'faizan' } };
var obj2 = obj;
obj.container = {};
```

Comment: so you mean that defining obj{} is creating a new objects with this name?? no concern to the upper obj??

Comment: so we have two object with same name obj and obj?? as you told that if i want to make null the upper obj then i need to do like this obj.container={}? i guess i didnt defined obj with var so why does this happen??

Comment: Objects don't have names. They just exist in memory, and variables can  point to them. When you do `obj2 = obj`, you're creating a second variable that points to the same object that `obj` pointed to. When you reassign `obj`, you're changing what it points to, but not what `obj2` points to.

Comment: ok but dont you think my this question and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521217/defining-an-object-with-var-or-without-var is same but the result is the different. This thing confusing me

Answer (score 0):

as you say :

```
obj={};
```

this way just refer the obj to a new reference in the heap , and the content

```
{name: "faizan"}
```

exsits in the heap as before  , and obj2 is refer the {name: "faizan"} in the heap now .

if you want to deep copy obj to obj2 , just like this :

```
function copy(o){
  var copy = Object.create( Object.getPrototypeOf(o) );
  var propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o);

  propNames.forEach(function(name){
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, name);
    Object.defineProperty(copy, name, desc);
  });

  return copy;
}

var obj={name: "faizan"}
var obj2 = copy(obj);
```

and then take obj refer null

```
obj = null
```

the GC will recycle obj automatically