# defining an object with var or without var

Tags: javascript, object

```
var ninja = { 
  yell: function(n){ 
    return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
  } 
}; 
console.log( ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "A single object isn't too bad, either." ); 

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell }; 
var ninja = null; 

try { 
  samurai.yell(4); 
} catch(e){ 
  console.log( false, "Uh, this isn't good! Where'd ninja.yell go?" ); 
}
```

the question is `Var ninja=null`

Is this another object?

or it same as i wrote it in first line?

I guess it is another new object cause i define it with var?

but this is false because out put is false and catch body ran. what the heck is this?
and i also have the same example like above but this is working differently why?

```
var obj={name: "faizan", age:31}
    var obj2 = obj;//obj2 pointing to the same memoray location of obj
    console.log("before making null obj::",obj2.name);
    console.log(obj==obj2,"::checking obj==obj2 while var obj2=obj");
    obj=null;  //obj became null
    console.log("after making null obj::",obj2.name);//now this will need to be null but is working why??
```

Comment: Dendens on the scope. If both the statements are in the same scope, they'll point to the same object.

Comment: Isn't this redefining the the var?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable can only be declared once in a particular scope. The second `var ninja = null;` ignores the `var` declaration, and simply reassigns the same variable, as if you'd written `ninja = null;`.

[JS Lint](http://www.jslint.com/) will warn about redeclarations of a variable.

Comment: now see this, this is working finevar obj={name: "faizan", age:31}
    var obj2= obj;//obj2 pointing to the same memoray location of obj
    console.log("before making null obj::",obj2.name);
    console.log(obj==obj2,"::checking obj==obj2 while var obj2=obj");
    obj=null;  //obj became null
    console.log("after making null obj::",obj2.name);//now this will need to be null but is working why??

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking, because comments don't have any formatting and I can't read the code.

Comment: what is the difference b/w ninja={} and ninja=null

Comment: The first one sets ninja to an object with no properties, the second one sets ninja to the value `null`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512461/a-object-property-value-is-showing-while-the-main-object-is-null